# How can I integrate User generated/dynamic fields in Contact form 7?

Tags: jquery

I have a custom php form on a site where user can click button to add to the form. Once they are done, they can send it.

The approach works OK but everything is custom written and prone to break. I would like to handle the form with Contact Form 7 but it does not have any options to handle user generated fields.

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Thanks very much

Comment: Gravity Forms has limited support for this type of thing, https://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/topic/add-new-fields-dynamically . I don't know of any way to get CF7 to handle them.

Comment: Can you explain what is Custom PHP form? Almost any code can be helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: I want to sell services (not fixed rate) from my website. The customer will have to pay for the service based on their input. Its a furniture assembly business and customer has to add all the different furniture articles dynamically so I can come up with the assembly cost. I have programmed all this in php and I use jquery. I can display the amount on the form but would like to add this amount to the Cart in Woo Commerce. Does that make sense ?